# sonar and maven multi-module project - can sonar analyze every module separately?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multi-module project, and O want sonar to analyze each project by himself. For example, to check duplicated lines only in the same module and not compere to all the project code?

Comment: Either those modules belong to the same project then the analysing is that way or if you need to have them separately analysed you have to separate them... I don't understand your problem?

Comment: I have some dev reasons to live all these modules in the same repo, so I cant separate them to different repos. So the question is if sonar can create different project in the same repo.

Comment: Can you explain those "dev reasons"? If you can separate them then why not doing it? You have to call SonarQube or your CI accordingly which makes your setup more complicated then necessary..simplify your setup ... it makes life easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to be separate from SonarQube's point of view, then you have to scan them separately.  SonarQube will not be "creating a different project in the same repo".  It doesn't care what the source location is for each project.

So, in your build process that runs the scans, you'll simply have to "cd" into each submodule directory and run "sonar:sonar" (or use the sonar-scanner), specifying the module name for each.  You'll need to ensure that the module name is a unique SonarQube project.